# Displaying corresponding XML nodes from different blocks

Tags: xml, xslt

lets say I have the following XML block..

```
<items>
    <books>
        <book>
            <name>a</name>
            <author>b</author>
        </book>
        <book>
            <name>d</name>
            <author>e</author>
        </book>
    </books>

    <infos>
        <info>
            <id>1</id>
            <year>c</year>
        </info>
        <info>
            <id>2</id>
            <year>f</year>
        </info>
    </infos>
</items>
```

Where each instance of 'info' corresponds to an instance of 'book'.  If items/infos/info/id refers to the position of a book element.
I'm trying to output the following...

```
a  
b  
c  

d
e
f
```

Thanks in advance... Any help would be apprechiated!

Answer (score 0):

If the nth `info` element matches up to the nth `book` then you can do it with careful use of the `position()` function.  For example

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="items/books/book" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:variable name="bookNum" select="position()" />
    <xsl:variable name="info" select="/items/infos/info[$bookNum]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="author" />
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$info/year" />
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Though for anything more complex than this simple example I'd probably define a separate template for the `info` element and put an `<xsl:apply-templates select="/items/infos/info[$bookNum]" />` in the `book` template, rather than putting it all inline.

Comment: Thanks for the input..  What if I wanted to use a foreach?

Comment: @user1748076 I'd tell you to use `apply-templates` instead ;-)  Seriously though, you can use exactly the same `position()` trick inside a `for-each select="items/books/book"`, it'll give you the same 1 for the first book, 2 for the second, etc.